# Connecting SVIs on different VRFs\same subnet - Nexus 9k

Tags: linux, networking, cisco, nexus

I am trying to do is create several SVIs in the same subnet.  This can be done by splitting them into different VRFs.

The only way I feel I can connect these VRFs (and SVIs) together is by creating a physical ethernet connection from VLAN 100 to VLAN 101's port for example.

This topology does not explain the whole story.  Try to imagine a hub and spoke with a bunch of different routers in the 192.168.1.0/24 space.

In this case I am trying to condense these routers down into one single N9K.

Is there a way to create "virtual wires" so that I can connect the SVIs together without burning physical ports.

[Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJDg7.png)

Comment: It could be me, but I re-read your post a few times and still don't understand what it is you're trying to do. Can you perhaps please try to rephrase, forgetting for a moment *how* you think you should do it, and instead emphasize on what functionality you are trying to achieve in the end.

Comment: BTW this might be more of a question for http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/